# How to use LoadGo animation in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to load my logo while open my website. So I am trying to use LoadGo animation get it from [Here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Image-Loading-Animation-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-LoadGo.html)

I need to integrate with my html page, it was loading in button click event. But how to change it in load event. How to properly integrate it when my website is loading.

Any Samples?

My code is here:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 150px;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <img id="cocacola" src="cocacola.png" alt="Coca Cola Logo" class="img-responsive logo"
            style="margin: 0 auto;" />
    </div>
    <div id="demo-progress-1" style="margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; opacity: 0;
        font-weight: bold;">
        0 %</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mainDemo();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>&nbsp;Start
    </button>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cocacolaInterval;
    function mainDemo () {
      $('#demo-msg-1').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
      });
      $('#demo-progress-1').animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      });
      var p = 0;
      $('#cocacola').loadgo('resetprogress');
      $('#demo-progress-1').html('0%');
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        cocacolaInterval = window.setInterval(function (){
          if ($('#cocacola').loadgo('getprogress') == 100) {
            window.clearInterval(cocacolaInterval);
            $('#demo-msg-1').animate({
              'opacity': '1'
            });
            $('#demo-progress-1').animate({
              'opacity': '0'
            });
          }
          else {
            var prog = p*10;
            $('#cocacola').loadgo('setprogress', prog);
            $('#demo-progress-1').html(prog + '%');
            p++;
          }
        }, 150);
      }, 300);
    };
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#cocacola").load(function () {
            // Main demo
            $('#cocacola').loadgo();
        }).each(function () {
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();
        });

        //mainDemo();
       // $(".container").hide();
    });
    </script>
```

After loading page logo will hide.

Answer (score 0):

Logo load

try this below code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(window).load(function($) {
                jQuery("#page_load").fadeOut("slow");
            });
        </script>
        <div id="page_load" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999999; background: #27599A url('cocacola.png') center no-repeat; background-size: 80px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pushed `mainDemo();` into 3'th line since the end.

```js
var cocacolaInterval;
    function mainDemo () {
      $('#demo-msg-1').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
      });
      $('#demo-progress-1').animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      });
      var p = 0;
      $('#cocacola').loadgo('resetprogress');
      $('#demo-progress-1').html('0%');
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        cocacolaInterval = window.setInterval(function (){
          if ($('#cocacola').loadgo('getprogress') == 100) {
            window.clearInterval(cocacolaInterval);
            $('#demo-msg-1').animate({
              'opacity': '1'
            });
            $('#demo-progress-1').animate({
              'opacity': '0'
            });
          }
          else {
            var prog = p*10;
            $('#cocacola').loadgo('setprogress', prog);
            $('#demo-progress-1').html(prog + '%');
            p++;
          }
        }, 150);
      }, 300);
    };
    
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#cocacola").load(function () {
            // Main demo
            $('#cocacola').loadgo();
        }).each(function () {
            if (this.complete) $(this).load();
            mainDemo();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Image-Loading-Animation-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-LoadGo/loadgo.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 150px;">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <img id="cocacola" src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Image-Loading-Animation-Plugin-with-jQuery-CSS3-LoadGo/cocacola.png" alt="Coca Cola Logo" class="img-responsive logo"
            style="margin: 0 auto;" />
    </div>
    <div id="demo-progress-1" style="margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 16px; opacity: 0;
        font-weight: bold;">
        0 %</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mainDemo();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>&nbsp;Start
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of LoadGo plugin (nice to meet you!). According to the docs:

> This plugin won't control asynchronous behaviour for your loading
>   process, so you have to do that by yourself in your app.

**LoadGo** is just a front-end plugin, which means that it won't manage any loading process for you, and you have to deal with this by yourself.

You can see a few insights here:

- https://github.com/franverona/loadgo/issues/8
- https://github.com/franverona/loadgo/issues/9